# Is it possible to add multiple lines in comments based on a condition using a counter?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code,

```
For m = 1 To no_of_ind
        For x = 2 To mx + 2
            If ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Comment.Text = Worksheets("Intermediate").Cells(m, n) Then
               ws.Cells(x + mx + 4, n).AddComment ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Value
            Else
            'do nothing
            End If
        Next x
Next m
```

Whenever the if condition is satisfied I will add a comment to a particular cell. If the condition is satisfied more than once, I want to add as many number of lines in the comments with appropriate text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For m = 1 To no_of_ind
    For x = 2 To mx + 2
        If Not(ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Comment) Is Nothing then
            CurrentComment = ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Comment.Text
        End If
        If ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Comment.Text = Worksheets("Intermediate").Cells(m, n) Then
            ws.Cells(x + mx + 4, n).Comment.Delete
            ws.Cells(x + mx + 4, n).AddComment CurrentComment & vbCrLf & ws.Cells(x + 1, n).Value
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
    Next x
Next m
```

You'll need to delete the current comment to add another, at least I couldn't get it to work without deleting the current comment. The code will give the two comments on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

---

When even I need to know how to do some like this I record a macro

```
Range("A1").addComment
Range("A1").Comment.Visible = False
Range("A1").Comment.Text Text:="Waldo:" & Chr(10) & "Sales are down %20 percent!!!"
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.29, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.78, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Range("F4").Select
```

**Next refactor:**

```
With Range("A1").addComment
    .Comment.Visible = False
    .Comment.Text Text:="Waldo:" & Chr(10) & "Sales are down %20 percent!!!"
End With
```

**And refactor again and again and ....**

```
Function addComment(TargetCell As Range, txt As String, isVisible As Boolean)

    If TargetCell.Comment Is Nothing Then TargetCell.addComment

    With TargetCell.Comment
        .Comment.Visible = isVisible
        .Comment.Text Text:= txt
    End With

End Function
```

Here are some handy character codes

- Tab: char(9)
- Line feed: char(10)
- Double Quotes: char(34)